# Maximum Degree of a Vertex in the Square of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm stuck on the following problem:

Given a simple graph with no loops or multiple edges, $G$, with $e$ edges, show that the vertex with the largest degree in $G^2$ (number of edges between $v_i$ and $v_j$ is the number of walks of length $2$ connecting $v_i$ and $v_j$), is at most $2e$.

How do I approach such a problem? I've been trying for a while and can't seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: What is your definition of walk here? Do you allow repeating edges? For example, if $vw \in G$, is $vwv$ a length $2$ walk for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the degree of $v$ in $G^2$ is the amount of vertices $w$ which are connected to $v$ via a length $2$ path. Your task is to show that this quantity is bounded above by $2e$, regardless of $v$. The Handshake Lemma states that

$$
2e = \sum_{v \in G}d(v).
$$

> As in the comments, fix a length $2$ path $vxy$. Hence $x \in N(v), y \in N(x)$. There are $d(v)$ options for $x$ and at most $d(x)$ options for $z$ (they are $d(x)-1$ since we can't repeat $v$). Hence the amount of possible paths is bounded by $\sum_{x \in N(v)}d(x) \leq \sum_{x \in G}d(x) = 2e$. This in turn bounds the amount of possible $y$, as desired.

Comment: I tried using this and saw that now, the problem boils down to showing that the # of walks with length 2 is bounded by the sum of all the degrees... When counting these walks, though, it is possible that an edge gets counted more than once throughout the entire process of walk-counting. How would I make a combinatorial argument to prove what I need?

Comment: you need to prove that the amount of vertices at the end of a length to path starting from a fixed $w$, is bounded by $\sum_v d(v)$. Fix $w$. A length $2$ path is of the from $wxy$ with $x,y \in G$. How many admissible pairs $(x,y)$ that fit into such a path are there? (note that we only need to count the amount of different possible $y$)